# AngularJS 1.6 and $onInit-Hook

Tags: angularjs, components, ngoninit

I'm trying to wrap my head around the change with AngularJS regarding the components' lifecycle hooks, especially `$onInit()`. I'm working with Todd Mottos Course, where he build a component which, in my opinion, should not work with 1.6, but it still does:

```
var repos = {
template: `
    <div class="repos">
        My Repos:
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="repo in $ctrl.list">
                <a href="{{ repo.html_url }}">
                    {{ repo.name }}
                </a>
                ({{ repo.stargazers_count }} stars)
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
`,
controller: function (ReposService) {
    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.list = [];
    ReposService.getRepos().then(function (response) {
        console.log(ctrl.list);
        ctrl.list = response;
    });
}
};

angular
    .module('repos')
    .component('repos', repos)
    .config(function ($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('repos', {
                url: '/repos',
                component: 'repos'
        });
    });
```

I don't understand, why

```
controller: function (ReposService) {
    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.list = [];
    ReposService.getRepos().then(function (response) {
        ctrl.list = response;
    });
}
```

still works, I thought "ctrl.list" would have to be initialized inside an $onInit, otherwise it is still undefined?

Comment: It is not wise to do it that way. The binding `list: '<'` provides a one-way binding from the outside controller to the isolate scope. The directive controller should only read the `list` property. It should not assign values to it.

Comment: Forget the binding, this was an error on my side, it wasnt in the original code.